# Need some help on this problem to merge these two codes

Tags: c++, c++11, clion

```
 #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char c;
    int n;
    cout << " Please enter a letter of the Alphabet and a decimal number";
    cin >> c >> n;
    if (c == 'a'|| c== 'e'|| c== 'i'|| c== 'o'|| c== 'u'||c == 'A'|| c== 'E'|| c== 'I'|| c== 'O'|| c== 'U' )
    {
        cout << c <<  " is a vowel" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << c << " is a consonant" << endl;
    }

    float x;
    cin >> x;
        if (x<0)
            cout << x << " is less than 0";
        else if (x>0&&x<100)
            cout << x << " is in range ";
        else
            cout << x << " is out of bounds";

        return 0;
}
```

The output is this when A, 41.5 is entered:

A is a vowel
nan is out of bounds.

I would like for the code to be able to find the answer to both and tell me whether or not it is below 0, in range, or out of bounds and also say that the letter is a vowel or a consonant, how could I go about doing this?

Comment: Get rid of `int n;` and the code that uses it.

Comment: That and do not enter a comma.

Answer (score 0):

Your input is incorrect.
Example correct input is:

```
A 0 3.13
```

Your code reads three inputs:

1. `char c`
2. `int n`
3. `float x`

Read this:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/cin-in-c/